# Driving a build process to build .net code via ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, msbuild, rake

I want to be able to build our small codebase from TeamCity and we have some rake scripts (written in ruby) which currently execute some other tasks and I am looking to add to these but am not sure where to begin as I am fairly new to ruby but have a little .net experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only just completed a project doing this at work, I wrote some pretty serious code in ruby that was executed via RAKE. However if I were starting again I'd take a look at the Albacore framework this can be found [here](http://albacorebuild.net/) which will save you a lot of the heavy lifting work we had to do.

Hope this helps.